# Print numbers from video frames to console using pytesseract

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, opencv

This is my first ever Python program. It checks every frame of a video file with Tesseract then uses OCR to recognise numbers in that frame and prints it to the console.

```
import pytesseract
import os
import cv2
import openpyxl
from numpy import interp
import numpy as np

# Video URL
TEST_VID = cv2.VideoCapture("VET2.mp4")
READING, IMG = TEST_VID.read()

# Frame Number
INDEX = 0

# Colours
black = [0, 0, 0]


while READING:

    TEST_VID.set(1, INDEX)
    READING, IMG = TEST_VID.read()
    RET, FRAME = TEST_VID.read()

    # If I want to print images
    # print("new frame: ", READING)
    # if not RET:
    #     break

    # # Assign a name for the file
    # NAME = "./image_frames/frame" + str(INDEX) + ".png"

    # # Assign the print statement
    # print("Extracting frames..." + NAME)
    # cv2.imwrite(NAME, FRAME)

    pixel = FRAME[2100, 1800]

    # If a pixel is black, use these values
    if np.all(pixel == black):

        # Image coordinates [y1:y2, x1:x2]
        speed = FRAME[2775:2883, 1199:1486]
        rpm = FRAME[2948:3014, 1190:1500]
        gear = FRAME[3187:3248, 1359:1415]

    # Tesseract directory
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (
        r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    )

    # Print KPH to console
    print(
        "Speed = "
        + pytesseract.image_to_string(
            speed,
            lang="formula1",
            config="--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789",
        )
    )
    # cv2.imshow("speed", speed)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Print RPM to console
    print(
        "RPM = "
        + pytesseract.image_to_string(
            rpm,
            lang="formula1",
            config="--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789",
        )
    )
    # cv2.imshow("rpm", rpm)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Print Gear to console
    print(
        "Gear = "
        + pytesseract.image_to_string(
            gear,
            lang="formula1",
            config="--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789",
        )
    )

    # cv2.imshow("gear", gear)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    print(INDEX)
    INDEX += 1
```

Comment: What version of python is this written in?

Comment: @Linny Python 3.7.3

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I rephrased your title to better follow the guidelines in [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) from the Help Center. An expressive title makes your question more appealing to reviewers.